# Is there any reserved space form custom application error codes?

Tags: executable, error-code, exitstatus

We need to define a few application specific error codes (exit status). Our use case: uninstaller si calling application to do online deactivation, which may fail for multiple reasons (no internet, internal server error,...). Is there any reserved interval for application specific error codes, so nothing would have chance to interfere?

Thanks

Comment: Just updated question, I am talking about application exit status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application gets to define its exit status however it likes.

Interpretation is completely up to the invoker. If that happens to be a shell, it will interpret any nonzero code as an error.

Comment: There is a list of [Windows System Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681381(v=vs.85).aspx). They go up to 15999. According to wikipedia's [exit status article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status#Windows), exit code is 32-bit signed integer. I guess it should be safe to use error codes over 16000, is it?

Comment: Error codes are distinct from exit codes. The exit code is basically just what shows up as the `errorlevel` in `cmd.exe`. Since you have a special invocation from the uninstaller anyway, it is the easiest way to just return something the uninstaller understands.

Comment: Searched a little more and found that 9009 as exit status have different meaning than error code. At least exit statuses 0,1,2,3,5 have the same meaning as error codes. But the way I run programs in (un)installer return system error code, so I can catch canceled UAC elevation (error code 1223). We will go for negative numbers. Thanks.